# Integral over unitary group: show that $\int_{U(N)} dU\, U_{ij}U_{kl}^\dagger=\frac{1}{N}\delta_{il}\delta_{jk}$

Tags: integration, group-theory, lie-groups, haar-measure

I am trying to show (to no avail),

$$ \int\limits_{U(N)} dU~U_{ij}U^{\dagger}_{kl} = \frac1N \delta_{il}\delta_{jk} $$

Where $dU$ is the normalized Haar measure on $U(N)$ and $U$ is a unitary matrix.  I have never seen anything like this before and the literature I've found is a little over my head.  Can these matrices be written in some other way to make sense of the integral or can we parameterize the group in some way? Any help is welcome.

Comment: you have somehow to go into the diagonal representation..i think about it

Comment: i think the key is that since the integral over the right hand side (call it  $J$ )i s invariant under unitary transformations $K$ and we might show that  $KJ=JK$. By Schur's Lemma we then have that $J\sim \text{Id}$. All what is left is to fix the constant of integration which shouldn't be too hard

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you are calling $J$.  Do you want to type out a more complete answer?

Comment: sry, i meant the complete $lhs$ should be denoted by $J$. Furthermore after some thinking i guess my reasoning only works for the case $j=k$. i will try to write up something rigorous

Comment: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m606/haar.pdf 
theorem 15 is what i had in mind (the argument goes through also in the general case)

Comment: Keyword "Schur orthogonality", applied to the "matrix coefficient functions" $U\to U_{ij}$ attached to the "standard" repn of $U(n)$ on $\mathbb C^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a simple-minded understanding of this result, just remember that the matrix elements of $U$ are random complex numbers. In particular, they have random arguments. So 
$$\int U_{ij}U^\dagger_{kl}=\int |U_{ij}||U_{kl}|e^{i(\theta_{ij}-\theta_{lk})}$$
The only chance of this integral not vanishing is if $\theta_{ij}=\theta_{lk}$.

Then you are left with the average value of the modulus square, $\int |U_{ij}|^2$. By symmetry, all elements of $U$ should have the same average. Since $\sum_i |U_{ij}|^2=1$ for all $j$, they should all have $1/N$ average.

If you want more general integrals over the unitary group you can look, for example, at the paper "[Moments and cumulants of polynomial random variables on unitary groups, the Itzykson-Zuber integral, and free probability](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0205010)", by Benoit Collins.

Comment: I'm confused by the statement "*The only chance of this integral not vanishing is if $\theta_{ij}=\theta_{lk}$*": $\theta_{ij},\theta_{lk}$ are integration variables here, not external parameters, so why do they need to be equal? The situation doesn't seem analogous to having something like $\int dx e^{x(\alpha-\beta)}\sim\delta_{\alpha,\beta}$. Could you be a bit more explicit on this point?

Comment: Well, if you have $i=l$ and $j=k$ from the begining, then you have a modulus squared. Otherwise, the result is zero.

Comment: yes, I am asking why is that the case, what's the reasoning?

Comment: Simply because $\int e^{i \alpha-i\beta}d\alpha d\beta=0$. This result is very fundamental and can be generalized to other groups and other irreducible representations.

Comment: right, so the gist is essentially that one can separate the integral into integrating over the phases and then integrating over the moduli squared. I guess this is because $U(N)$ can be decomposed into $SU(N)$ and $U(1)$?